# Code coverage not working for Jest test with Axios

Tags: javascript, jestjs, moxios

I am using `Jest` and `moxios` to write a test for my async function:

```
export function getData(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${'url'}/id`
    })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(setData(response.data));
      })
      .catch(() => alert('Could not fetch data');
  };
}
```

Test:

```
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import moxios from "moxios";
import getData from '../redux/getData';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore({});

describe('Test fetch data', () => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    moxios.install();
    store.clearActions();
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });
  it('should fetch data and set it', () => {
         const data = [{ name: 'John', profession: 'developer'}];
         moxios.wait(() => {
         const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
         request.respondWith({
           status: 200,
           response: data
         });
        const expectedActions = [setData(data)];
        return store.dispatch(getData()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
    });
  })
})
```

My test is passing, but when I check the code coverage report generated by Jest, it shows that the `then` block of `getData` was not covered/called. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did it gave you an error or nothing at all? By the way, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004395/how-to-test-async-function-making-use-of-moxios) it may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`moxios.wait` return `Promise` your test function return before running `except` functions.

you need to use `done` callback in your test function

```
it('should fetch data and set it', (done) => {
    const data = [{
        name: 'John',
        profession: 'developer'
    }];
    moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request.respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response: data
        });
        const expectedActions = [setData(data)];
        store.dispatch(getData()).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```